# converting string to date format like dd-mon-yyyy

Tags: vb.net, date

I have date value as string like `20200731` i have used to Below Code to Parse it with Exact date

```
Date.ParseExact(filenames.Substring(39,8).ToString(),"yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Output of above Expression is `07/31/2020 00:00:00` , However i want to get output like `31-JUL-2020`

Comment: I think the format you're after is dd-MMM-yyyy

Comment: The above expression doesn't have an output, it produces a `Date`.  Can you show the code that produces the string output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Console.WriteLine(Strings.Format(Date.ParseExact("20200731", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), "dd-MMM-yyyy").ToUpper)
```

Comment: Erro `was not recognized as valid date and time`

Comment: Hahahaha is your date (i had pasted in code your date). In your code works in my code doesn't?

Comment: My Mistake I used the Format Instead of `yyyyMMdd` anyway thanks for the Help It worked

Comment: Note that.: My example produce a String not a date as doesn’t make sense convert a date in the same date. There the difference is only on output in my code and Type of output inside Console.writeline is a “String”. As other devs above in comments said your code doesn’t produce an output. :)